# $A\in M_n$ is nonsingular, $A = BU$, and $U$ is unitary $\Rightarrow $ $A\overline A = B\overline B $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_n$ is nonsingular, $A = BU$, and $U$ is unitary.

Why does $A\overline A  = B\overline B $?

Comment: Write down $\overline{A}$ in terms of $\overline{B}$ and $\overline{U}$, multiply $\overline{A}$ with $A$, and use  the definition of unitary to conclude that $\overline{U}U = I$.

Comment: @akech - W e know that $A$ is invertible, what use of invertible ?

Comment: My bad, what is your definition of unitary?

Comment: What does the notation $\overline{A}$ mean?  The conjugate-transpose of $A$?  If so, the assumption that $A$ is nonsingular is unnecessary and irrelevant.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey - $\overline A $ is The conjugate of $A$ .

Comment: This isn't true if $\overline{A}$ is just the entrywise conjugate of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me stress a bit more:  the operation taking into account to say something about the chosen objects, is instead of $\overline{A}$ (which is simply a matrix with components as $\overline{A}=[\overline{a_{ij}}]$, complex conjugation of entries), one should be try the operation
$$A^*=\overline{A}^{\top}.$$
Precisely with this operation the unitary matrices are the elements $U\in GL_n(\Bbb C)$ such that $UU^*=1\!\!1$.

Then, if we have $A=BU$ for some unitary matrix $U$, we have 
$$AA^*=BU(\overline{BU})^{\top}=BU\overline{U}^{\top}\overline{B}^{\top}=BB^*.$$

We had used that $(PQ)^{\top}=Q^{\top}P^{\top}$ at transposing and $\overline{PQ}=\overline{P}\ \overline{Q}$ at conjugating, for any two matrices.

Answer (score 1):

$$A\bar{A} = BU\overline{BU} = BU\bar{U}\bar{B} = B\bar{B}$$

Comment: @janmarqz We know that $A$ is invertible, what used of invertible?

Comment: @H.S ... well, I suppose that $\overline{U}$ is the conjugate transpose of $U$.

Comment: @janmarqz Why?                                                          .

Comment: by definition, what else? a more used notations for an unitary matrix is $UU^*=1\!\!1$ where $U^*=(\overline{U})^{\top}$... you should check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix

Comment: and as Eric Wofsey said: invertibility of $A$ is irrelevant

Comment: @janmarqz - $\overline A $ is The conjugate of $A$ .

Comment: ok changing a bit $AA^*=BU(BU)^*=BU(\overline{BU})^{\top}=BU\overline{U}^{\top}\overline{B}^{\top}=BUU^*B^*=BB^*$ should be